# C# Reflection get nullable reference type

Tags: c#, system.reflection

```
public class A
{
    public A? MyA { get; set; }
}
```

We knew that a reference to `A` is always nullable, so using `A?` is actually redundant until ..... the introduction of nullsafety.

My question is, how can I tell if `PropertyInfo` of `A` has a `?` using reflection? `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Type)` does not work.